# LinFu version in NHibernate 2.1

Tags: nhibernate, linfu

I'm migrating the data layer of our application to NH version 2.1.0 (from 2.0.1) and noticed the use of LinFu. I discovered that framework and want to use it in other pieces of the application, especially I want to use the LinFu.Reflection.dll, which requires a reference to LinFu.DynamicProxy and here comes the trouble, the 1.0 final version of LinFu that I can find on google.code is not the same version used by NHibernate itself. Do I need to rebuild NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.dll changing the reference to the available version? If not, what else?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem a few days ago. There's a tool named ILMERGE that merges .NET DLL-files, and that way you should be able to have several versions of the same DLL in your application.

Unfortunately I haven't tested the tool yet, I didn't get around to it, but I'll test in the next week.

But Rhino Mocks for example, has a binary with all dependencies included: http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks/downloads.aspx, so it seems doable.